# Can set struct with bitfileds from C++ DLL to C# and then set it from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++

So in C++ i have a struct with looks

```
struct CPPSt {
    uint32_t var1[10];
    uint8_t  var2;
    int8_t   var3;
    uint8_t : 8; 
    uint8_t : 4;
    uint8_t var4: 4;
    int8_t  var5

    uint8_t var6: 2;
    uint8_t var7: 2;
    uint8_t var8: 2;
    uint8_t var9: 1;
    uint8_t var10: 1;
}
```

In C# (somelike)

```
public struct CSharpSt  
{
    public uint[] var1; 
    public byte var2; 
    public SByte var3; 

    public byte reserv1;
    public byte reserv2;

    public SByte var4; 
    public byte var5; 
    public byte var6; 
    public byte var7; 
    public byte var8; 
    public byte var9; 
    public byte var10; 
}
```

I found answer how to convert c# struct to long and its maybe a way to set that in c++, but how can i get it from c#? Or can you give a better idea

Comment: Unclear what your question is, but your C# declaration should be `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)] public uint[] var1;`

Comment: I mean is it easy way to set C++ struct to C#? Problem is that C# how i find doesnt have bitfields so i cant assign"C++ uint8_t var6: 2" to "C# public byte var6;" way i found to cast C++ struct to bytes array get it in C# and then use logical operator >>.

Comment: I need set struct from C# to C++ and  from C++ to C#

Comment: So what's wrong with bit shifts using `>>` and `&`

Comment: In my program it up to 60 variables and 3 structs like this so somethig like memcopy should be good)

Comment: You could make an extension method for `byte`. For example `public bool GetBit(this byte source, int bit) => (source >> bit) & 1 > 0;`